# tkinter GUI list of buttons

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, emoji

[image: Heres the gui I've created!]

```
for emoji, descriptor in emoji_descriptor
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("emojis/"+descriptor+".png"))
    b = Button(emojiApp, text = descriptor, 
               command=lambda x=emoji: appendEmoji(x), image=img)
    b.pack()

#after the list of buttons have  been made
for i in range(len(buttons)):
     buttons[i].grid(row = i//4, column = i%4)
```

Where `emoji_descriptor` can be a list of pairs of emojis with descriptions:

[(❤️,"red_heart"),
 (,"wink_tongue_out"),
 ...]

In this case I have 20 emojis/descriptors and the only one who's image shows up and who's button is actually active is the last one in the list. I've never used GUI for python so I'm not entirely sure how to resolve this error... Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't (easily) test this because the code in your question isn't complete enough to be runnable, but I think the problem is with the `img` variable's value being changed by the `for` loop.

Working around that might be a simple as passing the current value as a default argument to the `lambda` function you define—similar to what you did for the `x=emoji` argument to capture the current value of `emoji` and have it passed it to the anonymous function being created:

```
for emoji, descriptor in emoji_descriptor
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("emojis/"+descriptor+".png"))
    b = Button(emojiApp, text=descriptor,
               command=lambda x=emoji, img=img: appendEmoji(x), image=img)  # CHANGED.
    b.pack()
```

If that doesn't work, another alternative would be to save the current `PhotoImage` value by making it an attribute of the `Button` after it's created:

```
for emoji, descriptor in emoji_descriptor
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("emojis/"+descriptor+".png"))
    b = Button(emojiApp, text=descriptor,
               command=lambda x=emoji: appendEmoji(x), image=img)
    b.img = img  # ADDED to save value of img
    b.pack()
```

Comment: Sebastian Łącki: Out of curiosity, which of the two techniques worked for you?